# System grants the permission by no user action

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I am facing a strange problemm. I followed [this](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) tutorial in order to request permissions at runtime for an app i build. The problemm is that even though i check if the device is using Android M and i request permissions at runtime it does not show the dialog.

The code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.database_selection_spinner);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.proceedBtn);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ConfigurationActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
               accessWebService();
           }else {
               if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)){
                   StringGenerator.showToast(ConfigurationActivity.this, "Internet Permission needs to be granted");
               }

               requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, AppConstants.PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);

           }
        }else {
            accessWebService();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == AppConstants.PERMISSION_REQ_CODE){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                accessWebService();
            }else {
                StringGenerator.showToast(ConfigurationActivity.this, "LOL");
            }
        }else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

The accessWebService:

```
private void accessWebService(){
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask();
        task.execute(AppConstants.DATABASE_INFO_URL);
    }
```

The Manifest:

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

And there was no permission requested:

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet is a "normal permission", it is granted by the system without asking the user. See more in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html).

The user will be asked only for the [dangerous permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).